# Draw emoji on bitmap with drawTextOnPath

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, emoji

There is some conflict between using *canvas.drawTextOnPath* to draw emoji text on a bitmap.

When this method is used to draw emoji on a view's canvas it displays the emoji, but when used with a bitmap's canvas emojis dont appear only text appears.

Even if you tried to take screenshot of the view or try to draw the view on a bitmap, other text appears on the image but emojis don't. When the method *canvas.drawtext* is used emojis display on bitmap correctly.

did anyone encounter such problem or know a work around it ?

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawTextOnPath(" Hi this is a smiley emoji ", mArc, 0.010002136F, 27.510002F, Paint);
```

Only `Hi this is a smiley emoji` appears, but emojis don't.

And the parameters of the *drawTextOnPath* don't matter, whatever you use it still doesn't show.

Here is a sample to try, fully ready to test:
https://gist.github.com/mahmoudelfeel/ef3bb0baeaabad5ea8492831b04ce0fe